# CSS Drop down will will not become visible on hover, but will become hidden on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a hover dropdown menu. I can't get it to work. Currently, I have the menu to show and become hidden on hover. I tired just switching the visible and invisible, but that didn't work. I also tried changing the display, but that didn't work (it messed up the rest of my menu.)

```
/***************
menu_extend
***************/
nav ul li:first-child:hover + #menu_extend {

    visibility: hidden; 
}

#menu_extend ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nZg7Q/

Comment: why are you wrapping your block element in a span at all (even with a `display:` change...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the elements and the properties that you're setting don't match up. This way will work:

```
nav ul li:first-child:hover + #menu_extend ul {
    display: inline-block; 
}

#menu_extend ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Comment: This works, but my drop down disappears once I try to click click the nested li. I tried #menu_extened ul:hover {display: inline-block} but that didn't work.

Comment: Adding another rule for `#menu_extend ul:hover` setting the `display` to `inline-block` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Robby. I figured it out. I had to adjust my drop down so it overlapped with the menu item that created the drop down on the :hover. Before there was a gap between where my main nav ended and my drop down started. Thanks again for helping out a newbie!